The virtual phone in Android Studio is running but not displaying on the screen
When you launch a virtual phone in Android Studio, it does not appear on the screen, although Android Studio shows that the device is running. The virtual phone is also visible on the taskbar and is displayed in the device list when you press the WIN+R keys. However, it is still not on the screen.
It only helps once if I delete the virtual phone. If I close and try to open the virtual phone again, it will not be displayed again.
